# how to get a substring with varied length?

Tags: bash, shell, cut, substring

So i am writing a script which gets the substring from the input which is a path to a file `(/path/to/file.ext)` and if the directory `(/path/to)` does not exist it will run `mkdir -p /path/to` and then touch `file.ext`.

my question is this, how can i use `cut` to get the `/path/to` if we have a potentially unknown length of `/`'s

my script currently looks like this

```
INPUT=$0
SUBSTRING_PATH=`$INPUT | cut -d'/' -f 2`

if [! -d $SUBSTRING_PATH]; then
    mkdir -p $SUBSTRING_PATH
fi

touch $INPUT
```

Comment: Aside: `[! -d $SUBSTRING_PATH]` is [not going to work](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#if_.5Bgrep_foo_myfile.5D).

Comment: Aside: Come to think of it, testing that the path is a directory is unnecessary because `mkdir -p` won't do anything if it already exists anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `cut`, use `dirname` and `basename`:

```
input=/path/to/foo
dir=$(dirname "$input")
file=$(basename "$input")
```

Now `$DIR` is `/path/to` and `$FILE` is `foo`.

`dirname` will also give you a valid directory for relative paths to the working directory (I mean that `$(dirname file.txt)`  is `.`). This means, for example, that you can write `"$dir/some/stuff/foo"` without having to worry that you end up in a completely different directory tree (such as `/some/stuff` rather than `./some/stuff`).

As @ruakh mentions in the comments, if you didn't have a directory but a string of tokens of which you wanted to discard the last (a line of a csv file, perhaps), one way to do it would be `"${input%,*}"`, where the comma can be replaced by any delimiter. To my knowledge this is a bash extension. I only edit this in because a stray visitor in the future might have better luck seeing it here than in the comments; for your particular use case, `dirname` and `basename` are a better fit.

Comment: + 1; that is the best approach for the OP's purpose. Note that if these weren't filenames -- say, if you had `a:b:c:d:e` and wanted to lop off the `:e` -- you would write `input=a:b:c:d:e ; substring=${input%:*}`.

Comment: @ruakh, what would be the problem with using `"${input%:*}"` with file names?

Comment: @1_CR: It's not really a problem, it's just that `dirname` and `basename` are a bit smarter. For example, if the input is `/path/to/foo/`, they will return `/path/to` and `foo`, respectively, rather than getting fooled by the final `/`. And if the input is just `foo`, then `dirname` will return `.` (meaning "present working directory"). If you have very precise knowledge about shape of the input, then you don't need them, but if all you know is that it's a file-path, then they're the best way to process it intelligently.